# How to handle jQuery events through link tags

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a link on which I have attached an attribute `setnumber`.

```
 <a class="link-container" href="page1.html" data-setnumber="100">Link to page 1</a>
```

I want to get this attribute as soon as the user clicks on the link, then I will use this attribute through JQuery to save some information into the database.

```
$(document).on('click','.link-container',function(){ 
    var el = $(".link-container").attr("data-setenumber");
    alert(el);
});
```

After that or at the same time, I would let the user go to the requested page (page1.html).
But I never get into the JQuery file. I directly go to page1.html.
Is there a better way to do this with a link? The goal is to fill a mySQL table after the user clicks on the link, then bring the user to page1.html.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).on('click','.link-container', function(event){ 
    event.preventDefault();
    var el = $(".link-container").data("setnumber");
    alert(el);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `href` to go to the requested page `page1.html`. First get value of `data-setenumber` attribute and then redirect to `page1.html`.

```
<a class="link-container" href="javascript:void(0);" data-setnumber="100">Link to page 1</a>
```

```
$(document).on('click','.link-container',function(){ 
    var el = $(".link-container").attr("data-setenumber");
    alert(el);
    window.location.href = "http://localhost/page1.html";
});
```

Comment: Solution should be reactive he is on localhost but when it's deployed then what ?
I would suggest after playing with database related stuff, page should be redirected to link in href.